# What is Monad in kotlin arrow functional programming?

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming, monads, arrow-kt

Can someone explain the concept of `Monad` in `Arrow` functional programming?

https://arrow-kt.io/docs/datatypes/option/

Comment: Perhaps you should ask this on https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ ? This site is about practical programming problems.

Comment: https://arrow-kt.io/docs/patterns/monads/

Answer (score 6):

Here's a good explanation from the documentation:

> In Arrow terms, a Monad is an interface with two operations: a
>   constructor just, and flatMap

Arrow provides both documentation for [Monad](https://arrow-kt.io/docs/typeclasses/monad/) and a longer [Monad Explanation](https://arrow-kt.io/docs/patterns/monads/).

In a short and very non-academic way, though, Monad can be viewed as a design pattern to safely chain calls. If you used Stream API in Java, you've used monads. If you've used promises in JavaScript, you've used monads.

Comment: …if you've `map`ped and `concat`enated arrays, you've used monads. And thousands more.

Comment: @Bergi, though it may be confusing to the OP, `map` is actually part of `Functor`, not `Monad`.  And `concat` isn't really either (though it can be implemented in terms of `Monad`).  But this may be getting too pedantic.

Comment: @melston `flatMap` = `map` + `join`, where `join` is `concat` on arrays. Is there a `concatMap` method in Kotlin?